# easy-pie-chart zero percent renders as dot?

Tags: jquery, css

When I try to use easy-pie-chart with 0%, I'm still seeing a small dot being rendered at top/12 oclock position.

See screen shot. HTML/JS/CSS below.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[rendering of 0%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4o3a.png)
HTML:

```
<span class="chart" data-percent="25">
<span class="percent">25</span>
</span>
```

JS:

```
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
    animate: 2000,
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 12,
    lineCap: 'square',
    size: 100,
    trackColor: '#e5e5e5',
    barColor: '#00FF00',
    onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
        $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.chart {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.chart canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
}

.percent {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 110px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.percent:after {
  content: '%';
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `barColor = trackColor`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var charts = $('.percentage');
      charts.easyPieChart({
        animate: 1000,
        onStep: function(value) {
          this.$el.find('span').text(~~value);

          if(this.percentage == 0)
            this.options.barColor = this.options.trackColor;
        },

      });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9ukvu7ph/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong. I don't know if one of them is yours but there are several [similar issues on plugin's GitHub page](https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart/issues/189).

The plugin draws a line. In this case, it starts a line at 0, ends at 0 and applies a 3px thick stroke with rounded end-caps creating a little dot at the starting point.

In your code, you could just check if value is more than 0 and simply not display it at all, or chime in on GH and wait for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 'lineCap' to 'butt'. It helped me